# How to extract text from a string in Bash using Grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, cut

I have been using Grep with Cut to gather info from log files, but I am having trouble extracting a string when the word count in the line changes, eg;

The line could be

```
[2014-12-31 21:00] Host: Word1 (LOCATION) [140.56 km] 38.582 ms
```

or

```
[2014-12-31 12:00] Host: Word1 Word2 (LOCATION) [76.50 km] 49.508 ms
```

or

```
[2014-12-31 12:00] Host: Word1 Word2 Word3 (LOCATION) [76.50 km] 49.508 ms
```

With my current code,

```
host_=`grep Host: $FILE | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f4-`
```

I am able to get the following

```
Word1 Word2 (LOCATION) [140.56 km] 38.582 ms
```

What I would like to do is only get the word(s) plus the location in brackets and not the remaining information so that I end up with this

```
Word1 Word2 (LOCATION)
```

The distance and time at the end of the string (whilst they change values) are always in that same position and "date/time" and the word "Host:" are always at the beginning of the string.

Could anyone here point me in the right direction to what I need to use?

I have tried googling and not found anything, but I am not exactly sure what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: does this help? `grep Host: $FILE | tail -1 | grep -Po '.*Host: \K.*\)'`

Comment: @Kent - That works perfectly, thank you very much. I will make sure that I learn how and why that works. Thank you again

Comment: ok, I added as answer and with brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep Host: $FILE | tail -1 | grep -Po '.*Host: \K.*\)'
```

The interesting part is the last `grep`:

- -P using perl regex
- -o output only matched part
- `\K` similar as look behind, but supports dynamic length
- `.*\)` match the part you need

Comment: or perhaps `grep -Po 'Host: \K.*\)' $FILE | tail -1`

Answer (score 1):

This one is actually not that difficult to do if I am understanding the question right. The following simple `regEx` within your `grep` will return only the requested part of each line.

**Example**

```
grep -Po  '((?:\w+\s?)*\(\w+\))' FILE.TXT
```

**FILE.TXT**

```
[2014-12-31 21:00] Host: Word1 (LOCATION) [140.56 km] 38.582 ms
[2014-12-31 12:00] Host: Word1 Word2 (LOCATION) [76.50 km] 49.508 ms
[2014-12-31 12:00] Host: Word1 Word2 Word3 (LOCATION) [76.50 km] 49.508 ms
```

**Result**

```
Word1 (LOCATION)
Word1 Word2 (LOCATION)
Word1 Word2 Word3 (LOCATION)
```

**[REGEX100](https://regex101.com/r/yF8rB6/1)**

It will match forever until you reach a `(word)` which will be the last thing captured. It also does not require any piping or output redirection.

*Thoughts* Personally when I am working within the a shell and have to do ANY string manipulation like you are doing above I go straight for `regEx` as it is what all the shell commands use internally to return your results. Take for instance `grep` or *globally search a regular expression and print*. RegEx is an invaluable tool and only really takes a few minutes to learn the basics of.